# How do I programmatically test authorization for URLs in Spring Security?

Tags: authorization, spring-security

I'm using Spring security 3.0.5 in a JSF 2 application.

In order to deactivate/hide entries in my navigation menu for users that are not permitted to access them, I need a way to programmatically test whether the currently logged in user is allowed to access a given URL.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution myself: the API for this functionality is found in [`WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html), which can be acquired via an `@Autowired` spring bean.

Comment: I want to do a similar thing. Can you answer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-securi

Comment: Michael, do you know if WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator runs for urls bounded to SpringMVC controller methods with @Preauthorize annotations?

Comment: This doesn't work for `@PreAutorized` and `@PostAuthorized` annotations