# how to implement dynamic intercept url pattern i.e from database in spring security 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring-security

I am new to spring security so not getting how to proceed for making the Url's to be authenticated should come from database.
What things to be added in applicationContext-security.xml and what custom java classes will be needed?
Please help me with example.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with you. The following links would be helpful.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-dynamic-url-metadata

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?112799-How-to-dynamically-decide-lt-intercept-url-gt-access-attribute-value-in-Spring-Security

[How to dynamically decide <intercept-url> access attribute value in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-securi)