# How to generate permission matrix from spring mvc security configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In our project we're mixing xml and annotations based spring mvc security configuration. We've got quite a few lot of roles, a lot of controlers and frequently changing requirements about who should be able to do what. I thought it would be nice to have util class which will generate permission matrix [like this](http://permissionmatrix.jpg.to/).

What I've done so far is wrote simple [classpath scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime) which looks for all classes marked with [@Controller](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.java) and extract values of [@PreAuthorize](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.java). Naming convention for controllers is straightforward: {Action}{Type}Controller (eg. NewOrderController) so its easy to generate human(and by human I mean non-programmer) readable csv file.

The problem is classpath scanning for annotation doesn't cover what we've got in xml config.

I was wondering if there is any other way to query metadata used for access resolution by spring mvc itself.

**EDIT**:

Example xml configuration (largely simplified):

```
<security:http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />

<security:http auto-config="false"
               use-expressions="true"
               entry-point-ref="entryPoint"
               security-context-repository-ref="securityContextRepository">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/product/**" access="hasAnyRole('PRODUCT_USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN_USER')" />
    <!-- No security configuration for /order/** -->
</security:http>
```

Example of annotation driven configuration:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/order/new/{id}")
public class NewOrderController {

    @Autowired
    public NewOrderController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ORDER_USER')")
    public ModelAndView display() {
        return new ModelAndView(/*...*/);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ORDER_USER')")
    public RedirectView process() {
        return new RedirectView(/*...*/);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide parts of the XML config that you need to cover?

Comment: I've added extract from security config. I can't post production code but that should give an idea how we configure this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898824/248082) will help you construct the solution to parse and load the meta data on URL interceptors in order to gather the configured roles.

Comment: Thanks Nobeh, I'll take a look on weekend if I can craft something based on security meta data.

Comment: I tried to prototype this solution but it seems to be a bit more complex than so I decided to go with class scanning. Thanks for the answer anyway. I'd use FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser, but for different purpose.