# add URL in spring security at run time without restarting application

Tags: spring-security

In my java based web application user want to add his URLs in the application. I have used spring security which picks users as well as some predefined URLs from database.
Now if user want to add new URL and allow his own URL ( which is not in my secured URL list)
I may need to put that URL in DB, restart the application and then user will login and hen he can access that URL.
I want user can provide this URL at run time and will just log out and log in. Spring security should authorize that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Store your url and authority rules in a domain class which implements [DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource  -- Requestmap](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.html) table, which can be updated dynamically.

Comment: But when application is deployed at that time bean of  DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource will be created. and it will fetch all URLs from DB. When application is up and user wants to add new URL how can I add that URL in the object of  DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource hold in the bean. As per my info. we should not modify bean definition once it is deployed as it may have dependent beans also.

Comment: You can define your domain class which implements it. This is some details about how to persist these rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-secur