# how can I manage spring security url pattern in java class instead of xml config

Tags: spring-security

I'm beginner in spring security and I have a problem with that((I used spring security 3.1)).
I have a project and I have to read all spring security url pattern from Db instead of springSecurity application context.

how can I do it?
my point is how can I manage access to special url in my java classes instead of use below config in  springSecurity application context.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/customer/showAll" access="hasAnyRole('OPERATOR,ADMIN')"/>
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide your own implementation of **FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource**.
In the **Collection getAttributes(Object object)** method you can load your patterns and access parameters from DB ([see default implementation](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java)).
Each pattern must be converted into RequestMatcher object. An access attribute value must be converted into a collection of ConfigAttribute objects. As an input object you will have incoming request. You must populate **requestMap** from DB.
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-secur#6898824) how configure Spring Security to use your own FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource implementation instead of default ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.