# Spring security dynamically add users and authorities

Tags: spring-security

How to generate "intercept-url" dynamically. My user name and roles are stored in database,
I want to map all these users in to spring security.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific what your goals are? You want to secure user specific URLs (e.g. `/my-app/user/{userName}/**`)?

Comment: Yes i want to secure URLs. But which user is authorized to access the page that data i want to store in database.

Comment: Spring's `WebExpressionVoter` might be of interest to you.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-secur

Comment: The accepted answer in the referenced question is overly complex and non-dynamic (security metadata are parsed only during application startup). Using custom SPeL method via `WebExpressionVoter` check is better.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide your own implementation of com.icod.solapCore.spring.security.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.

This could look like this :

```
public class MyFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

      @Override
      public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        FilterInvocation filterInvocation = (FilterInvocation) object;
        HttpServletRequest request = filterInvocation.getHttpRequest();
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> result = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();
        // Find roles in database that secures the specified request
        // ...
        // For any role found, create a SecurityConfig object prefixed with "ROLE_" ex : 
        // for(String role : roles) {
        //   ConfigAttribute attribute = new SecurityConfig("ROLE_"+roleFound);
        //   result.add(attribute);
        // }

        return result;
      }

      @Override
      public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
      }
}
```

And then you'll have to replace the default FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource with your own.  I do it with a BeanPostProcessor, called after spring read the configuration file but before it makes the configuration official.  Looks like this :

```
public class MyFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

  private FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource = new MyFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource();

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource) {
      return metadataSource;
    }
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Then you just have to configure the bean post processor :

```
<bean id="solapcoreFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor" class="foo.bar.MyFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Give all your users same role and operate with this role in config.

You can read abour roles [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/authz-arch.html)

Comment: Thanx for reply. But this link can't help me in my solution.