# Modify spring security intercept URL dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-security

can i have any way to modify the "access" parameter of intercept-url pattern for any url dynamically.

That means; i have URLs for different purpose and suddenly i want to stop (from UI) a particular URL (to change it's access="denyAll").

Is there any way??

Answer (score 2):

You should implement custom class FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource that is used by FilterSecurityInterceptor. For details look here [How to dynamically decide <intercept-url> access attribute value in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-secur)