# How to make spring security dynamic

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a web app which uses `spring security basic authentication` .

So now if i hit the url.. server sends a 401 and my browser show the username/password popup.

Every thing is fine.

But now i want that a user can login and can change the access as anonymous i.e.

If now user hit the url he/she will be directly able to see the content without 401 or a redirect

How to do that since xml is hardcoded ?

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-secur

Comment: Not sure I understood the question, but that's the way basic authentication works. The user has to close and reopen the browser to see a new login dialog.

Comment: @Henry which part you dont understand

Comment: @user2410148 what you mean by "change the access as anonymous"

Comment: @Henry means a user login and tick the checkbox which says "remove security" or "don't do authentication"

Comment: I don't think you can do this out of the box. But Spring Security is highly customizable. With a few lines of Java code you should be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it right but what you want can be done with separating your "dynamic part" into some URL subtree (i.e. "/dynamic/**") and permitting everyone to access this part with single filter rule.